# Split Python string based on HTML code &#8213;

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a program that scrapes quotes along with authors. The issue comes with formatting the output. The actual quote is only the first small part of an html class, so to output correctly I need to split the string. Here's a small html snippet:

```
<div class="quoteText">
      &ldquo;No matter how long you train someone to be brave, you never know if they are or not until something real happens.&rdquo;
  <br>  &#8213; <--- want to split string here
  <span class="authorOrTitle">
    Veronica Roth,
  </span>
    <span id=quote_book_link_11735983>
      <a class="authorOrTitle" href="/work/quotes/15524542">Insurgent</a>
    </span>
```

And here's the relevant python code:

```
for quote in quotes: 

            body = quote.find(class_="quoteText").get_text(strip=True).split('-',1)[0]  # using '&#8213;' doesn't work either
            author = quote.find(class_="authorOrTitle").get_text(strip=True).split(',',1)[0]

            all_quotes.append({"body" : body, "author" : author})
```

Currently this will split the string later in the html causing a bunch of gibberish to be outputted.

So basically I need help converting that particular html to something python can recongnize, or an alternative way to **only** get the quote. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what information are you intending to extract by parsing this html content ?

Comment: I'm just trying to extract the quote itself without any extra html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your split is not working because `&#8213;` is not a regular hyphen, it is a Unicode [Horizontal Bar](https://www.unicompat.com/2015) character. BeautifulSoup converts it from an HTML entity to an actual Python Unicode character, so that's why searching for the string `"&#8213;"` isn't working either.

The Unicode hexadecimal code for that character is `2015`, so you can use

```
body = quote.find(class_="quoteText").get_text(strip=True).split('\u2015',1)[0]
```

However, this is pretty fragile. What if there is a quote in your document that does use a regular hyphen instead of the horizontal bar character? Then it won't work.

If you know you'll always have newline characters (`\n`) after the quote, you can use that to get something that at least doesn't rely entirely on a specific, rare Unicode character:

```
body = quote.find(class_="quoteText").text.lstrip().split("\n")[0]
```

But that's also not super reliable, for example if you have a newline inside your quote. You could split the code on the `<br>` tag itself (which BeautifulSoup will convert to `<br/>`), but that feels hacky and again relies on specific formatting.

Since you know these are all quotes, presumably always surrounded by quotation marks, you can use a regex match to get all of the text inside the quotes. The code below checks for regular quotes as well as curly double left and double right ones:

```
import re

body = quote.find(class_="quoteText").text
quoteText = re.findall(r'(?:"|\u201c)(.*)(?:"|\u201d)', body)[0]
```